# Can not specify the configuration location of kerberos for hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I am testing my first Job running with ToolRunner. To run it I defined a krb5.ini file On Windows, that is as such:

```
[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
kdc = kerberos.example.com
admin_server = localhost
dns_lookup_kdc = false
}
```

I put it in `C:\Windows\`

Then, I tried to specify the location of it for my code with these ways:

1. Adding for main code the argument of `java.security.krb5.config=C:\Windows\krb5.ini`
2. Adding the address of `krb5.ini` to known Libraries of my project
3. Defining the environment variable for OS (Windows 7) with this:
   `KRB5_CONFIG = C:\Windows\krb5.ini`
   Although [this page](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html) had told that "You can override the default location by setting the environment variable KRB5_CONFIG. Multiple colon-separated filenames may be specified in KRB5_CONFIG; all files which are present will be read."
4. Specifying the location of krb5.ini with System.setProperty as such:

---

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "C:\\Windows\\krb5.ini");
    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.realm", "C:\\Windows\\krb5.ini");
```

Non of these ways didn't resolve this error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get Kerberos realm
at org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(HadoopKerberosName.java:65)   at org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(HadoopKerberosName.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:275)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:790)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:760)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:633)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2812)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2802)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2668)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
at org.enahang.mapreduce.utils.mrUtils.Test.run(Test.java:125)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.enahang.mapreduce.utils.mrUtils.Test.main(Test.java:62)
```

My environment is netbeans, and before trying these ways I approximately knew that these ways don't work. I often can resolve such problems by adding a proper jar file as an external library. any ideas? or a hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: try to **improve** the Kerberos config, instead of wondering why it just does not work as-is. For instance, try the `default_realm` clause:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm    = EXAMPLE.COM
dns_lookup_kdc   = false
dns_lookup_realm = false

[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = kerberos.example.com
}
```

You may also need to define `permitted_enctypes`, `default_tkt_enctypes`, `default_tgs_enctypes`, `forwardable` etc. depending on your Kerberos implementation.

Comment: Good idea. But it didn't work for me. I think java has aggregated all config files containing the definition of it I've added them to my code, and so it has reduced the priority of my commands. However, because it was my first test, I removed the `hadoop-auth` to get my code running

Answer (score 0):

This is a java app... so it's going to be expecting slashes in the opposite direction in your path to the config file... so:

```
C:/Windows/krb5.ini
```